# Help with terminology & methodology for a hierarchical (& imbalanced) classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a dataset that I am not sure how to analyze, or at least I am not sure of the terms to read up on. I have 25 groups. Each group belongs to one of 3 locations. Each group consists of multiple individuals, and every individual has 3 categorical predictor values. Importantly, the number of individuals in each group is not the same.

My goal is to predict the locality of 5 'testing' groups, which match the training groups but don't have a location. So I'd like to use the makeup of the individuals in a group to predict the location of the group. It is a classification model, maybe, but it has the hierarchical nature of individuals -> groups -> location. I would like to avoid any ordination if possible. Does this have a name? Any tips on what to search for?